# How to understand this kind of condition in if statement?

Tags: c, if-statement, struct

The code below is part of the program. I don't know how to understand `if(!conn)` and `if(!conn->db)`.  It's not obvious as a condition, I mean not like `if(a==b)`.

Then can anyone help me understand this kind of `if statement` it in English? Thanks in advance for your answers!

```
struct Connection *Database_open(const char *filename, char mode)
{
     struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
     if(!conn)die("Memory error");

     conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
     if(!conn->db) die("Memory error");

     if(mode == 'c')
     {
          conn -> file = fopen(filename, "w");
      }

     else{
            conn -> file = fopen(filename, "r+");
            if(conn->file){
            Database_load(conn);
            }
     }
     if(!conn -> file) die("Failed to open the file");

     return conn;
}
```

Comment: the -> does is deference a pointer(pointing towards an object) and then use the ‘ . ‘ operator on the leftover expression

Comment: The `if (!conn->db)` means the same as `if (conn->db == 0)` or `if (conn->db == NULL)`.  There are those who love the shorthand; personally, I don't use it in my code.  You also find `if (conn->db)` which is equivalent to `if (conn->db != 0)`.  It works with any numeric or pointer type when you compare to `0`; if you're sane, you only compare pointers with `NULL`.  Note too that the spaces around the arrow `->` (or dot `.`) operator, as in `f(!conn -> file)`, are wholly inappropriate.  The arrow and dot operators bind very tightly; the should not be surrounded by space.

Comment: `if (!conn) die ...` means if the connection is false, then die.  It is just a boolean condition.  It still evaluates to true or false, just written differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you need to know what are truthy values and what are falsy values in C:

- Zero is a falsy value while non-zero is truthy.
- For pointers, `NULL` is falsy while non-`NULL` is truthy.

Truthy values evaluates to true while falsy evaluates to false.

---

Equipped with this information, lets check out `if(!conn)`. Here, `conn` is a pointer and `!` is the logical NOT operator that inverts its operand. So,

- If `conn` is `NULL`, `!conn` will be non-`NULL` and the condition will be true.
- If `conn` is non-`NULL`, `!conn` will be `NULL` and the condition will be false.

So, in short, it tells the program to `die` in case the memory allocation for `conn` fails.

---

Now, lets check out `if(!conn->db)`. Here, `conn` is a pointer, `->` is the arrow operator, `db` is one of the members of `conn` and `!` is the logical NOT operator that inverts its operand.

Now, `conn->db` fetches the value of the member variable `db`.

- If `conn->db` is `NULL`, `!conn->db` will be non-`NULL` and the condition will be true.
- If `conn->db` is non-`NULL`, `!conn->db` will be `NULL` and the condition will be false.

So, in short, it tells the program to `die` in case the memory allocation for `conn->db` fails.

---

These two conditions are the same as `if(conn == NULL)` and `if(conn->db == NULL)` respectively, as mentioned by [@JonathanLeffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) [in the comments section](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43511320/how-to-understand-this-kind-of-condition-in-if-statement/43511597#comment74076518_43511320)

Answer (score 0):

The logic is as Cool Guy said - values are checked against zero (NULL is also 0).
You can read more about it on:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/if